# Prove that, if $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$, then $a^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$ solves the congruence $x^2 \equiv a$ mod $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

The condition $p \equiv 3$ mod $4$ is necessary to the good definition of $a^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$, but other than that I don't know any other useful property of these kind of primes.
I tried to use the Fermat's little theorem: $(a^{\frac{p+1}{2}})^2 \equiv a^{p+1} \equiv a^2$ mod $p$, then $a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \equiv \pm a$ mod $p$, but now I don't know how to conlude that $a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \equiv a$ mod $p$.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here.  Not every number is a square $\pmod p$.  For instance, $\pmod 7$, the non-zero quadratic residues are $1,2,4$.  So there is no solution to, say, $x^2\equiv -1\pmod 7$.  In particular $(-1)^{(7+1)/4}\equiv 1\pmod 7$.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the assumption that $a$ was a quadratic residue?

Comment: Yes, your right, a has to be a quadratic residue. It was probably implied although not explicitly written in the statement. Thank you.